# access ubuntu programs from wmii

Tags: window

I'm using the wmii desktop manager and I'd like to find a way to access ubuntu programs.

wmii does not have a menu as such so I either need to add the ubuntu menu somehow or else find a list of the ubuntu system programs so I can execute them by name.

Answer (score 1):

Use M-p (M being you meta key, that's either Alt or "Windows key")
Then you get a list of commands you can run, you can type the command or use auto-completion.

There is no "Menu" in wmii though. I started using wmii about 2 weeks ago and I love it! Hope you find at ease using it.